# VSTS Build Configuration, how to copy files from a specific folder

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint

Here is the structure of files in my vsts project:

```
$/intra
  -BuildProcess Tempalates
  -intra-DEV
       -Project
          -Solution-1
          -Solution-2       
  -intra-QA
  -intra-PROD
```

I have defined the build configuration for the infra-DEV branch and then building the solution via MSBuild. And on the xext step i am trying to copy the build'ed files from $(Build.SourcesDirectory) to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory).

Here, when i use "" in the 'contents' section, it will copy the below folders and the files in it

```
-$/intra
-BuildProcess Tempalates
-intra-DEV
```

but how can i copy only the `-intra-DEV` folder and the contents inside it.